# Thread sleep VS wait condition

Tags: c++, multithreading, async-await

## EDIT :

The point here is to know the more efficient solution for implement a wait loop which poll a condition on every iteration. By efficient, I mean "efficient for CPU scheduling".

I know that the wait condition used in my code is not a "real wait condition" used witch a "wakeOne"/"wakeAll" instruction but I want to know if using a fake wait condition is more effective for the CPU than a sleep.

## Original post :

Here is 2 code snippets, which does the same thing : wait until something happen. This code is used in a pool of worker threads. So when a thread wait, the others (or some of the others) should process their instructions.

The first use a "sleep", the second a "wait condition".
They are written with Qt, but could be easily translated to C++11, Boost or any thread library.

The both works well, but is there any performance difference ? I remember that I've read somewhere :

> The "sleep" cause an active wait, so the CPU spend time to wait.
>
> The "wait condition" make the CPU wait for an event, so the CPU switch to another thread execution during the wait

Do I remember well ? Is that true ? Using a wait condition is more effective to execute multiple threads in parrallel ?

The "sleep" version :

```
while (someCondition == false)
{
    sleep(100);
}

// Do some work
```

The "WaitCondition" version :

```
QMutex mutex(QMutex::NonRecursive);
QWaitCondition waitCondition;

while (someCondition == false)
{
    QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
    waitCondition.wait(&mutex, 100);
}

// Do some work
```

Comment: *"The "sleep" cause an active wait, so the CPU spend time to wait."* False.

Comment: Could you point to some documentation about sleep / wait conditions to confirm that ?

Comment: @Jarod42 I think OP means that his "sleep" solution does some (light) busy waiting as condition is polled...

Comment: I think the efficiency is very system dependent. I believe that once i saw the one of implementation of wait() function of condition_variable, is just sleep 20 ms and check the condition

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDITED:**

Both versions are identical, as both "block" or "suspend" (that is - remove it from the "runnable" list in scheduler) the calling thread.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sleep.html http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_timedwait.html

During sleep and wait for CV the thread does not use any clock cycles of the CPU.

**ORIGINAL:**

The difference is significant. The first example (with sleep) will react to an event within 0-100ms. The other - with condition variable - will react "instantly". That is because the sleep will do just that - sleep for the exact amount of time you requested (note - let's assume that your system does not use POSIX-style signals). On the other hand, condition variable will wait for as long as you requested **unless** it receives a notification that the condition might have changed.

Comment: In this example, the wait condition is used to create a "sleep", so the 2 codes does the same : wait about 100ms. The important question here is not "how many time do we wait" since this is a waiting loop, but "does the CPU can work on other tasks during the wait"

Comment: @Aurelien - in both cases the CPU can be rescheduled to other threads while the one in your example sleeps, but you seem to miss the point how the condition variables work. If in the "other" thread you have `waitCondition.notifyOne();` near changing `someCondition` to `true`, then the CV wait will be interrupted immediatelly, not when the time runs out.

Comment: I know how to use "wait condition" and "notifyOne" / "notifyAll". The wakeup is immediate, and I use that often for consumer/producer patterns. The point here, in this question, is to know if it's more effective (for CPU scheduling) to use a sleep or a "miss-used" wait condition.

Comment: "sleep" solution clearly regularly moves the thread from sleeping queue to runnable queue, so there exists some overhead, while "wait" definitively pushes the thread onto some event-waiting queue until the event comes. Worst, in "sleep" you need to ensure that the variable to test is not cached onto some register...

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer I was looking for.